# Stretch to first full page with resizing img

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, resize, stretch

I made a simple first page, but i want content to start on the second page, as soon as the user scrolls

The current implementation isn't optimimal in crossbrowser / cross device circumstances (tablet, phone, desktop, ...). Is there an easy way to adjust or implement it?

I have created [the simple example here](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8539/), it's not bad as a first experiment, but it ain't good either.

As you can see, the black part is the start of the second page.. So that shouldn't be visible..

```
<h3>This is the html code</h3>  
<div class="container body-content">
<div class="row page" id="first-page">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>MemberPop</h1><hr>
        <h3>Superkrachten om uw leden en betalingen te beheren.</h3><hr>
        <img id="popeyeIMG" src="http://membershipmanagement.azurewebsites.net/Images/Backgrounds/Popeye.jpg"><br>                                       <br>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Account/Register">Probeer het gratis</a> <br>
        of <a class="" href="/Account/Login">Log in</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the simple script to resize the image:

```
 var clientHeight = $(window).height();
 var firstPage = $("#first-page").height();
 if (clientHeight < firstPage) {
     var Relation = (firstPage / clientHeight) * 1.3 ;
     $("#popeyeIMG").height($("#popeyeIMG").height() / Relation);
 }
```

Any advice on what i should improve to stretch the first part of the page to the full page in any circumstances (mobile, tablet, desktop)?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `$("#first-page").height(clientHeight);` in the end of your js file

I would also add some media-queries to fit your h1 and h3 (and possible #popeyeIMG instead of defining it using relation)

Something like this

```
@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method has a severe lag :(

Comment: Normal scrolling example http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html#firstPage